# Vectorize nested for loop - homemade geocoding

Tags: r, lapply

I am analizing my google location history (dumped from [here](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout), if anyone is interested).
Now, the dataset doesn't include any field containing the name of the city, but given there's a lat/lon combination for every row we can compute it ourselves.
Given my dataset is 1.2M rows long, using free geocoding APIs is out of the table (traffic is obviously throttled).

#### Data

Couple airport locations

```r
airport_coords <-
  structure(
    list(
      V1 = c("LIMC", "LIRF"),
      V2 = c("MXP", "FCO"),
      V3 = c("MALPENSA", "FIUMICINO"),
      V4 = c("MILANO", "ROME"),
      V5 = c("ITALY", "ITALY"),
      V6 = c(45L, 41L),
      V7 = c(37L, 48L),
      V8 = c(53L, 46L),
      V9 = c("N", "N"),
      V10 = c(8L, 12L),
      V11 = c(43L, 15L),
      V12 = c(40L, 11L),
      V13 = c("E", "E"),
      V14 = c(234L, 4L),
      V15 = c(45.631, 41.813),
      V16 = c(8.728,
              12.253)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

And here's a few lines of a simplified version of the location history from google

```r
loc_history <- 
  structure(list(latitudeGPS = c(41.8713521, 41.8713478, 41.8714064, 
41.8714201, 41.8713419, 41.8713981, 41.8713237, 41.8714538, 41.8713845, 
41.8714139, 41.8714417, 41.8714538, 41.8714417, 41.8714538, 41.8714538, 
41.8714538, 41.8714538, 41.8714538, 41.8714594, 41.8714594), 
    longitudeGPS = c(12.4414861, 12.441478, 12.4415342, 12.4415539, 
    12.4414757, 12.4415345, 12.4414538, 12.4415871, 12.441514, 
    12.4415466, 12.4415735, 12.4415871, 12.4415735, 12.4415871, 
    12.4415871, 12.4415871, 12.4415871, 12.4415871, 12.4415954, 
    12.4415954)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Scrappy solution

My approach is to compute the distance between the the lat/lon coordinate and the airport of the cities I'm interested in geocoding (from [this](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) dataset), assuming that if the distance is < 50km I am looking at the city where the airport is located (which should be plenty accurate for my needs).
I have written the following `for` loop (i know...) that works, albeit being terribly slow. I am looking for ways to turn this dumpster fire into something faster using vectorized functions like the `apply` family.

```r
library(raster)  # for pointDistance
library(dplyr)

# Init empty df to store results
dist <- data.frame(
  dist_mt = NA,
  city = NA
)
for (i in 1:nrow(loc_history)) {

  # Tmp df to store computed distances
  tmp <- data.frame(
    dist_mt = NA,
    city = NA
    )

  for (x in 1:nrow(airport_coords)) {
    # Coompute point - airport distance
    v <- pointDistance(c(data[i,]$latitudeGPS,
                         data[i,]$longitudeGPS),
                       c(airport_coords[x,]$V15,
                         airport_coords[x,]$V16),
                       lonlat = TRUE)

    # Append to tmp dataframe
    tmp[x,]$dist_mt <- v
    tmp[x,]$city <- airport_coords[x,]$V4  # Keep city label
  }

  # Append city if distance < 50km
  if (min(tmp$dist_mt) <= 50000) {
    dist[i,] <- filter(tmp, dist_mt == min(dist_mt))
  } else {
    dist[i,]$city <- "other"
  }

}
```

### Performances

The loop takes around 4 seconds to process ~1.0000 rows. Having 1.2M rows it'd take ~80 minutes to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a matrix from your data rather than passing in one value at a time as per the `pointDistance` help document:

> **Arguments**
>
> **p1**    x and y coordinate of first (set of) point(s), either as c(x, y), matrix(ncol=2), or SpatialPoints*.
>
> **p2**    x and y coordinate of second (set of) second point(s) (like for p1). If this argument is missing, a distance matrix is computed for p1

So to get the whole thing in one gulp, you would do

```r
pointDistance(  
  matrix(c(loc_history$longitudeGPS, loc_history$latitudeGPS), ncol=2),
  matrix(c(airport_coords$V16, airport_coords$V15), ncol =2), 
  lonlat = TRUE) -> distmat

distmat
#>           [,1]     [,2]
#>  [1,] 513625.5 16943.33
#>  [2,] 513625.5 16942.53
#>  [3,] 513622.8 16949.33
#>  [4,] 513622.4 16951.42
#>  [5,] 513625.9 16942.10
#>  [6,] 513623.5 16949.00
#>  [7,] 513626.6 16939.65
#>  [8,] 513620.9 16955.40
#>  [9,] 513623.8 16946.85
#> [10,] 513622.6 16950.60
#> [11,] 513621.4 16953.84
#> [12,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [13,] 513621.4 16953.84
#> [14,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [15,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [16,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [17,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [18,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [19,] 513620.8 16956.27
#> [20,] 513620.8 16956.27
```

Since each column represents the distance to each airport (in order as they appear in your airport data frame), if you find the minimum from each row, you will find the index of the airport. You can do this with `apply`

```r
loc_history$nearest_airport <- apply(distmat, 1, function(x) 
         { if(x[which.min(x)] < 50000) airport_coords$V4[which.min(x)] else NA })
loc_history$distance_to_nearest_airport <- apply(distmat, 1, min)
```

and this should be the result you were looking for:

```r
loc_history
#>    latitudeGPS longitudeGPS nearest_airport distance_to_nearest_airport
#> 1     41.87135     12.44149            ROME                    16943.33
#> 2     41.87135     12.44148            ROME                    16942.53
#> 3     41.87141     12.44153            ROME                    16949.33
#> 4     41.87142     12.44155            ROME                    16951.42
#> 5     41.87134     12.44148            ROME                    16942.10
#> 6     41.87140     12.44153            ROME                    16949.00
#> 7     41.87132     12.44145            ROME                    16939.65
#> 8     41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 9     41.87138     12.44151            ROME                    16946.85
#> 10    41.87141     12.44155            ROME                    16950.60
#> 11    41.87144     12.44157            ROME                    16953.84
#> 12    41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 13    41.87144     12.44157            ROME                    16953.84
#> 14    41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 15    41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 16    41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 17    41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 18    41.87145     12.44159            ROME                    16955.40
#> 19    41.87146     12.44160            ROME                    16956.27
#> 20    41.87146     12.44160            ROME                    16956.27
```

You should get an `NA` in the nearest_airport column if there is no airport within 50km.

In other words, you could replace your whole "dumpster fire" with:

```r
distmat <- pointDistance(  
  matrix(c(loc_history$longitudeGPS, loc_history$latitudeGPS), ncol=2),
  matrix(c(airport_coords$V16, airport_coords$V15), ncol =2), 
  lonlat = TRUE)

loc_history$nearest_airport <- apply(distmat, 1, function(x) 
         { if(x[which.min(x)] < 50000) airport_coords$V4[which.min(x)] else NA })

loc_history$distance_to_nearest_airport <- apply(distmat, 1, min)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to pass a `matrix` as input, I believe this can turn out to be useful. On the other hand, how do I grab the corresponding city label from `airport_coords` dataframe after comparing which distance is < 5000?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated. As a note, I am favoring this solution as it doesn't require any additional package.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `sf` and `lwgeom` packages:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
airport_coords = st_as_sf(airport_coords, coords=c('V16', 'V15'), crs=4326)

loc_history = st_as_sf(loc_history, coords=c('longitudeGPS', 'latitudeGPS'), crs=4326)

dist = st_distance(loc_history, airport_coords)
dist
#> Units: [m]
#>           [,1]     [,2]
#>  [1,] 513625.5 16943.33
#>  [2,] 513625.5 16942.53
#>  [3,] 513622.8 16949.33
#>  [4,] 513622.4 16951.42
#>  [5,] 513625.9 16942.10
#>  [6,] 513623.5 16949.00
#>  [7,] 513626.6 16939.65
#>  [8,] 513620.9 16955.40
#>  [9,] 513623.8 16946.85
#> [10,] 513622.6 16950.60
#> [11,] 513621.4 16953.84
#> [12,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [13,] 513621.4 16953.84
#> [14,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [15,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [16,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [17,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [18,] 513620.9 16955.40
#> [19,] 513620.8 16956.27
#> [20,] 513620.8 16956.27

closest = apply(dist, 1, 
            function(r) ifelse(min(r)<=50000, airport_coords$V4[which.min(r)], NA))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: sf also has the function `st_nearest_feature()` which might help.